# Expected ';' after top level declarator in Core-plot iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot, xcode6.4

[image]I have included Core-plot framework into my project using cocoa-pods. The build fails at these locations:

```
typedef NSArray<NSNumber *> *CPTNumberArray;
typedef NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> *CPTMutableNumberArray;
```

Can't figure out what the error is.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you get any build errors? If yes, please edit them into your post.

Comment: pls check the build errors now

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

For working with Objective C Light Weight Generics, you need to set your base sdk as iOS 9 or greater

**Suggestion**

If you are trying to declare it, no need of that `typedef` keyword. Just use:

```
NSArray<NSNumber *> *CPTNumberArray;
NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> *CPTMutableNumberArray;
```

And if you are trying to create a type definition for easy access, you can define it like:

```
typedef NSArray<NSNumber *> CPTNumberArray;
typedef NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> CPTMutableNumberArray;

// Declare objects like
CPTNumberArray *numArray;
CPTMutableNumberArray *numMutableArray;
```

It looks more Objective C kind of way, if you declare it like:

```
typedef NSArray<NSNumber *> *CPTNumberArray;
typedef NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> *CPTMutableNumberArray;
```

You need to create objects like:

```
CPTNumberArray objArr;
CPTMutableNumberArray objMutArr;
```

That looks odd to me in Objective C context.

Comment: The Core-Plot framework is having declarations like this. I didn't declare them myself. I am not sure how they the core-plot team would approve if  this was a mistake. What do u think?

Comment: @vikramchowdary: It seems like a typo to me. I'm sure that won't be the correct syntax

Comment: @vikramchowdary: What is your base sdk ? iOS 9 ?

Comment: it's iOS 8.4 and using Xcode 6.4

Comment: @vikramchowdary: You need to set base sdk as iOS 9 or greater. Check the updated answer

Comment: @ Midhun : Yes i think so, i'm actually installing Xcode7 :)

Comment: Finally it worked with Xcode7. I still don't understand what the issue is, in core-plot documentation it says the base target for iPhone is 8.0 and doesn't work if i set that .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91738/discussion-between-vikram-chowdary-and-midhun-mp).